# Is there any chance that I can use vncserver in level 3?

Tags: linux, vnc, runlevel

I see another guy use noVnc making a webshell for linux,  it's not graphic and its running level3 as in the picture below. Does anyone know how to run vncserver in level3? 
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a mistake to ask this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are on run level 3. 
You can start a VNC server, using the vncserver service, and connect to it remotely. Your session will be graphic.
If you want to connect remotely to a shell, you can just use ssh instead.
You can use this link http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server
That explains how to do it.

Comment: Actually, it's a question about vnc in kvm.I'm sry that i didnt describe it properly.I think i'll use ssh instead.